# ASP.Net Core appsetting.json databaseconnection understanding

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have inherited a code which has the following connection string in the appsetting.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConnection": "Server=EC2AMAZ-XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=XXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }
```

What I do not understand is, how EF Core connects to the database while the full db address/URL is not provided in the connection string. Could you help me understand?

Comment: probably you have set DNS records in your network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use URL. The server part uses IP and name resolution. In your case, it is using name resolution.

Name resolution is done by name servers which is called as DNS.

What I see in your connection string is more like computer name. If the computer name is your own pc your pc do not need to ask anything to DNS.

If you are in the same workgroup name resolution also works inside same workgroup.

If you are in the workspace environment and if your computer is on domain. There is most probably a DNS server which resolves domain names.

If the target system is on Internet, your computer asks to Global DNS servers to get the ip address of the named host.

Comment: That is not the case unfortunately.

Comment: I might have misunderstood you, please explain your issue with more details. Is the case about constructor initialization? or are you asking network related question?

Comment: The "server" attribute in the connection string is just a simple "xxx" string. To my knowledge it must be a URL. Now I am wondering how EF Core knows where is the DB endpoint.